# Android - Code is not working to set text of EditText to bold

Tags: java, android

I want to make the text in `EditText` bold `onClick` of a button, but the code below gives me an error when I run the application in the emulator the error is `The application chatApp has stopped unexpectedly`, yet when I take this code out it works fine.

Code

```
 private void setBoldText() {
    final EditText sendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myMessage);
    Button boldButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBold);
    boldButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: put your logcat here.

Comment: where are you calling this method? you have to put this or call it when the view is created. If you have a View already define somewhere you should use: `EditText sendMessage = (EditText) your_view.findViewById(R.id.myMessage);`

Comment: Try `Google` buddy..!! and define this code snippet in `onCreate` as said by @Dyna

Answer (score 0):

Try..this code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText ed;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "fonts/your.ttf");
               ed.getText().toString();
                ed.setTypeface(tf);

        }
    });
}
```

Put ur custom fonts in assets-> fonts folder...
Hope this will help u... it is working...

Answer (score 0):

the below code will work

```
edit.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="tp" >
   <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>  



 Button boldButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBold);
boldButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendMessage.setTextAppearance(ClassName.this, R.style.tp);

    }
});
```